# SQL - Choose which field to select

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable

Ok, the title may be a bit strange, but what i'm trying to do doesn't seem quite complicated.

I have a table **myTable** with two fields **defaultName** and **customName**. I would like to make a query that selects the **customName** if it's not null neither empty, otherwize the **defaultName** who is always not blank.

I'd be grateful to any help or link to a related post.

Comment: is it [tag:sql-server] or [tag:mysql]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server syntax:

```
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN customName IS NOT NULL AND customName <> '' THEN 
             customName
           ELSE 
             defaultName
         END AS customerName
    FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select case 
    when isnull(customName, '') = '' 
        then defaultName 
        else customName 
    end as customerName
from table
```

This is a better SQL Server solution. The ISNULL function and NULLIF functions are good to learn, as well as the COALESCE function.